# Are typedefs exposed in the final binary? Are they available in symbol files and in RTTI?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, symbols

At the moment I am creating scoped typedefs inside functions for function pointers, does this carry on to the final binary or is it similiar to the preprocessor macros? (Find & Replace)

Comment: @hvd I didn't say that. But will remove the comment right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typedefs are not just like macros, they are a first-class C++ language feature not just a textual find&replace done by the preprocessor. But they are not usually expressed in the resulting binary, except for some cases explained below.

A type has a "name for linkage purposes" which is it's "true name" that gets used by the compiler and linker to decide if two types are the same. When you use a typedef the compiler will convert that back to the actual type that it refers to. There are cases where the typedef name is used for linkage purposes, such as when the type has no real name, such as an anonymous struct or anonymous enumeration type e.g.

```
typedef struct { } anon_struct;

typedef enum { E=1 } anon_enum;

void f(anon_struct*, anon_enum);
```

The function `f` needs to use the names of its argument types in its mangled name, but since the types don't have names the typedef names will be used instead, and those typedef names could appear in the binary.

Another way that typedefs might get expressed in a binary is in debug symbols, which are additional, optional data included in the binary that are  not executed or used at run-time, only by debuggers and similar tools.

Answer (score 4):

No they don't carry though. They don't behave like the preprocessor at all.

At least not with the MSVC compiler (assuming exported functions). And I don't believe with the others either.

Typedefs are essentially an aliasing mechanism.

Given a level of optimization and symbols stripping, very few symbols make it the final release binary anyway.